# Load JSON file into a dictionary and not string or list

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary, web-scraping

I have created a JSON file after scraping data online with the following simplified code:

```
for item in range(items_to_scrape)
    az_text = []
    for n in range(first_web_page, last_web_page):
            reviews_html = requests.get(page_link)
            tree = fromstring(reviews_html.text)
            page_link = base_url + str(n)
            review_text_tags = tree.xpath(xpath_1)
            for r_text in review_text_tags:
                review_text = r_text.text
                az_text.append(review_text)
    az_reviews = {}
    az_reviews[item] = az_text
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(az_reviews , outfile)
```

There might be a better way to create a JSON file with the first key equal to the item number and the second key equal to the list of reviews for that item, however I am currently stuck at opening the JSON file to see the items have been already scraped.

The structure of the JSON file looks like this:

```
{
  "asin": "0439785960",
  "reviews": [
    "Don’t miss this one!",
    "Came in great condition, one of my favorites in the HP series!",
    "Don’t know how these books are so good and I’ve never read them until now. Whether you’ve watched the movies or not, read these books"
  ]
}
```

The unsuccessful attempt that seems to be closer to the solution is the following:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

json_data = open('data.json', 'r').read()
json1_file = json.loads(json_data)
print(type(json1_file))
print(json1_file["asin"])
```

It returns a string that replicates exactly the result of the print() function I used during the scraping process to check what the JSON file was going to be look like, but I can't access the asins or reviews using `json1_file["asin"]` or `json1_file["reviews"]` since the file read is a string and not a dictionary.

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Using the `json.load()` function I still print the right content, but I have cannot figure out how to access the dictionary-like object from the JSON file to iterate through keys and values.

The following code prints the content of the file, but raises an error (`AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'items'`) when I try to iterate through keys and values:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as content:
    print(json.load(content))
    for key, value in content.items():
        print(key, value)
```

What is wrong with the code above and what should be adjusted to load the file into a dictionary?

Comment: "I have tried many ways" is not helpful. No one can tell what kind of mistakes you made if you don't show what you tried.

Comment: I have updated the question with the wrong attempts, could you spot which mistakes I have made? Thanks

Comment: Do you think all of your attempts should work? Do you think someone shoud analyse each of them. Pick one which you think should work, then try to figure out why it does not. Google it. Then ask a specific question saying e.g. I expected this function to do one thing (e.g. because specification says so), but it did another thing. Show what happened wrong. Then you will have a valid question. See also [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You should really be using `json.load()` if you have a file

Answer (score 0):

> string indices must be integers

You're writing out the data as a string, not a dictionary. Remove the dumps, and only dump

```
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(az_reviews, outfile, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

> what should be adjusted to load the file into a dictionary?

Once you're parsing a JSON object, and not a string, then nothing except maybe not using reads, then loads and rather only `json.load`

---

Another problem seems to be that you're overwriting the file on every loop iteration

Instead, you probably want to open one file then loop and write to it afterwards

```
data = {} 
for item in range(items_to_scrape):
    pass # add to data
# put all data in one file 
with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f)
```

In this scenario, I suggest that you store the asin as a key, with the reviews as values

```
asin = "123456"  # some scraped value 
data[asin] = reviews
```

---

Or write a unique file for each scrape, which you then must loop over to read them all.

```
for item in range(items_to_scrape):
    data = {} 
    # add to data
    with open('data{}.json'.format(item), 'w') as f: 
        json.dump(data, f)
```

Comment: Thanks cricket_007 for sharing your knowledge, I will probably re-adjust the scraping code to have only asin number and reviews text, which will make the output JSON file lighter and more appropriate.However, I need to figure out how to access the keys and values from the JSON file because one of the requirements for the scraping code is to access and factor in the asins already scraped and inside the file and scrape only the ones remaining in my list.

Comment: You access data from a parsed JSON file the same way as any other dictionary

Comment: I get the "AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'items'" error when I try to iterate through the keys and values after the json.load() function. I included that part at the bottom of the edited question, what do you think is wrong with that part of the code?

Comment: Attempted code is the following:

with open('data.json', 'r') as content:
    print(json.load(content))
    for key, value in content.items():
        print(key, value)

Comment: I have edited the scraping code to dump the asin as key and the reviews as values, fixing also the mistake removing the dumps and leaving only the dump to write the JSON file.What other mistake is there in the question?

Comment: `key, value in content.items():` won't work because `content` is a file handle, not a dictionary. Perhaps you meant to assign `json.load` to a variable, then use `.items()` on that?